# libGDX How to stop touchUp registering if user moves finger after touch down

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a scrollPane with several actors inside. each actor has a touch event registered to set a new screen, but users will obviously want to be able to scroll through the list of actors without the touches registering. how do I go about this? the actors are registering touch events as below...

```
public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
    octave3Btn.getColor().a = 0.25f;
    return true;
}
public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
    octave3Btn.getColor().a = 1f;
    launcher.setScreen(new ListNotesScreen(NoteNameAssets.octave3NoteNameArray,ImageAssets.octave3BtnTextureArray,manager, launcher));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`touchDragged`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html#touchDragged%28int,%20int,%20int%29) callback to know whether there was a drag in between, or not.

```
private boolean wasDragged = false;

public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    octave3Btn.getColor().a = 0.25f;
    wasDragged = false;
    return true;
}

public boolean touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
    // you can use a simple flag here, or better calculate the distance
    // and set the flag when the distance surpassed a certain limit
    wasDragged = true;
}

public boolean touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    octave3Btn.getColor().a = 1f;
    if (!wasDragged) {
        launcher.setScreen(new ListNotesScreen(...));
    }
}
```

This should probably take small errors into account. You would probably not set the flag in case there was a drag event for 1px. Better calculate the distance that the touch was dragged in between `touchDown` and `touchUp` and then switch the screen in case `distance < 10` for example.

Comment: thanks, this solution works so I will mark it as correct, but I have also just fount through experimenting that instead of using an InputListener, if I use an ActorGestureListener, this behaviour is already implemented!

Comment: Good remark, I didn't even know that this class exists!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best solution is to use `clicked()` instead of `touchUp()`. I know this question is 3 years, I write it for "future generations" :)

```
myButton.addListener(new ClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y)
    {
        //do your stuff
        super.clicked(event, x, y);
    }
});
```